# how to change the div height property to auto when I click on '"more" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

there is a list of elements and i need to expand each element on click the more button and collapse each element when click on the less button. but when i click to more button all div will open at the same time also i can't close them . click on the less button.
here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidi{
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hidi">
<div class="uner-sch">
1
</div>
<div class="uner-sch">
 2
</div>
<div class="uner-sch">
3
</div>
</div>
<div class="more"> ... More +</div>

<div class="hidi">
<div class="uner-sch">
1
</div>
<div class="uner-sch">
 2
</div>
<div class="uner-sch">
3
</div>
</div>
<div class="more"> ... More +</div>

<script>
$(".more").click(function(){
var el = $('.hidi'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000),
          $(this).text('... less -');


});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to use `css` with `jquery`  ----> `$("yourclass").css({"height":"auto"})`

Comment: it works fine but it works in all divs i want to execute this code for each when i clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
        3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
        3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var curHeight = $('.hidi').height();
$(".more").click(function(){
    var container = $(this).parent('.container');
    var el = container.find('.hidi');
    var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    if(el.hasClass('open')){
        el.removeClass('open');
        el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... less -');
    }
    else{
        el.addClass('open');
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... more +');
    }
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hwunuz7b/

Comment: @inaz khahesh mikonam ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works when you change `var el = $('.hidi')` into `var el = $(this).prev()`. With the new code the 'more button' refers to his own .hidi div.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6dL5svL6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery UI`](https://jqueryui.com/) and use [`addclass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) & [`removeclass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to animate it.

**CSS**

```
.open {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".more").click(function() {
  // check if it is open
  if ($(this).hasClass('toClose')) {
    // if open , then remove class open and add back hidi
    $(this).prev('.open').removeClass('open').addClass('hidi', 1000);
    // update text
    $(this).removeClass('toClose').text('... More +')
  } else {  // if it is in closed state
    $(this).addClass('toClose').text('... less -');
    $(this).prev('.hidi').addClass('open', 1000).removeClass('hidi');
  }
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy61matz/3/)